# Gitlab remote access

Tags: git, gitlab, versioning, vpn

I'm working with Gitlab only recently and have the following question:

We have an installation of Gitlab on our local server in the office. I would like to access it from home and work with the repositories. I've done some research, but I have not found a solution that I understand.

How can I access this local Gitlab installation from external (home office) and what do I need for it?

I hope I can ask such questions here and I hope you can help me.

Comment: If you can not access to the local machine where your Gitlab server located, then you can not access to your Gitlab repo neither.

Comment: And how should I get on my local machine to use gitlab?

Comment: Sounds like you need to VPN into your work network? Worth talking to your IT department about getting that setup...

Comment: What is the VPN for? Can gitlab only be accessed locally?